# What is the server-side these days for Mobile Application

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, cloud, server

I recently started developing an android app but i starting to think about , what is my server-side gonna be.

So far i learned about J2EE and that i can make WebServices with it , by running them on a server like Apache Tomcat / GlassFish / Jetty / Oracle etc...

Today as you know there is Cloud Storage , but what i dont understand is when i write my server-side in java for example with GlassFish. How do i deploy it to run on cloud / hosting server and control it.

What i am aiming with my question is that how do you setup a server side for android/ios application.

Thanks

Comment: Try Bluemix http://www-01.ibm.com/software/bluemix/
You can setup your cloud environment in minutes and be ready to publish your work in no time.

Comment: @Mark thanks but what right now i am trying to do is to try understand the idea of that